# control of the direction of a inputbox extends in html

Tags: html, css

I am reading the HTML and CSS code of http://preview.python.org/, I have sth don't understand:
Please look at the search-box. How to achieve the icon-search? I don't think it is a jpg or png file,
how to make it?
And, when you focus the input box, it extends from right to left, how to achieve it? I test some input box, it doesn't act like this way.
Thanks.

Comment: The icon is just generated content - use a DOM inspector like FireBug or something and inspect that element, then you see it. And the extending of the input field can be done by a simple CSS transition when the field has `:focus`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the CSS `transition` property. Have a look at the example code below:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
  <script>
    function revertBackWidth(){
      console.log("calling");
        document.getElementById("s").style.width="100px";

    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onmousedown="">
  <input type="text" class="s" id="s" onchange="revertBackWidth()">
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
input {
width: 100%;
padding: .65em;
margin-bottom: .875em;
border: 1px solid #caccce;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
-ms-border-radius: 6px;
-o-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
  width:100px;  
    float:right;
    position:relative;

}

.s{
  -webkit-transition: width .3s ease-in-out;  /* Chrome 1-25, Safari 3.2+ */
  -moz-transition:width .3s ease-in-out;  /* Firefox 4-15 */
  -o-transition: width .3s ease-in-out;  /* Opera 10.50–12.00 */
  transition:width .3s ease-in-out;  /* Chrome 26, Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */

}
#s:focus
{ 
width:200px;  
}
```

[Live Demo For Reference](http://jsbin.com/onaman/1/edit)